# php-fpm and pcntl_fork

Tags: nginx, php

I'm issuing a serious problem using php-fpm and pcntl_fork.

Both are working pretty well, but when they are together, I "loose" standard output for web browser. This mean the fork works, but the standard output (client browser) is totally lost for everybody (all children and the parent).

Outside fpm (in command line for example) the fork works as expected (all children print to terminal output).

Does someone gone something working or it's general problem with php-fpm ?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I finally found the good way...

The code I use (which can be found at many place) use `exit(0)` function on child process to terminate it. But on php-fpm this also kill the main process... That's why it was not outputing after first child call...

Here is solution (found on `pcntl_fork` user comment):

```
register_shutdown_function(create_function(
    '$pars', 'ob_end_clean(); posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL);'
), array());
```

This will kill as expected any zombie at the end of script without killing main process